# Is there any way to indent code for full module/script?

Tags: excel, vba, indentation, code-readability

VBA excel: Is there any way to indent code for full module/script in VBA at once?

It's ctrl+I in matlab and everything has the correct identation...

Comment: If you install the Rubberduck plugin, there is a tool for that (https://rubberduckvba.com/). There is nothing natively built-in in VBA.

Comment: Or MZ Tools0: https://www.mztools.com/

Comment: you can highlight the rows desired to indent then press 'Tab' to indent all those rows at once. 'Shift' & 'Tab' will remove one indent on any highlighted rows. There is nothing to auto-indent entire code at once. Alternatively, tools available online: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba-code-indenter/